# Payment processors with WordPress Caldera Forms and CiviCRM

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, payment-processor, caldera-forms

We need some help to set up a **CiviCRM Event registration form** using **Caldera Forms** and a **Payment Processor**.

But we haven't be able to find any **Payment Processor plug-in** that integrates with Caldera Form in order to take payments and create the corresponding data entities in CiviCRM,
as Caldera Forms are no longer supported, and it is not possible now to get a license for neither of these the plug-ins:
Caldera Forms Stripe, Caldera Forms PayPal Express and Caldera Forms Authorize.net.

I have seen there is plug-in
***Caldera Forms eWAY Rapid API Payment Processor*** developed by *Agileware*, but it seems it is only available for businesses in Australia and New Zealand.

We can not use the online registration form that provides CiviCRM as we need to create the relationships between participants and
also displayed the existing relationships of the contact that is logged in to the system.

Any help on how to address this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Which payment processor you want to integrate?

Comment: Ideally Stripe, but I suppose our non-profit could use PayPal